# JSTree fragmentation issue in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jstree

I'm attempting to build a file explorer in Rails and am having a strange issue with some sort of fragmentation of my JStree. (see picture below)

[image]

I'm suspicious that it has something to do with this line in my JavaScript file, but I'm not exactly sure. (**the full JS file is further down**)

```
'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,
```

The reason I'm suspicious of this line of code is because in another project, I got the JSTree to build correctly, but I was doing it without any AJAX calls.

But, now that I'm making an AJAX call using JQuery to have the server reply with JavaScript to build up the JSTree, I'm getting this weird fragmentation.

Would anyone be able to explain why this is happening?

---

**myView.html.haml**

```
%a.btn{id: 'open-test-data-directory'}
#treeViewDiv
```

---

**application.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '#open-test-data-directory', function() {
  $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/fire_ajax",
  dataType: "script"
})
```

---

**routes.rb**

```
get '/fire_ajax', to: 'ajax#go'
```

---

**ajax_controller.rb**

```
def go
    @folders = directory_hash("/home/jeffrey/Documents/Ruby_Workspace/OLD_Learning Ruby On Rails - Working Files/Chapter 12/timetracker/tmp")

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :my_jserb_file}
    end
end
```

---

**my_jserb_file.js.erb**

```
function buildMyJStree(){
return $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({ 
    'core' : {
        'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,   // <----- Suspicious line!!!
        'themes' : {
            'name' : 'proton'
            }
        }
   });
}

buildMyJStree();
```

---

### **UPDATE**

Actually, I'm not so sure my "suspicious line" has anything to do with this.  I went ahead and tried manually creating the data for the JStree and the same visual issue is occurring in the tree.  Please see the code below ::

```
function buildMyJStree(){
 $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({ 
    'core' : {
        // # 'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,   // <----- Suspicious line!!!
        'data' : [
            {   'text' : 'Root 1',
                'children' : []
            },
            {
                'text' : 'Root 2',
                'children' : [
                    {'text' : 'Root 2 kid 1'},
                    {'text' : 'Root 2 kid 2'}
                ]
            },
            {
                'text' : 'Root 3',
                'children' : []
            }
        ],
        'themes' : {
            'name' : 'proton'
            }
        }
    });
}

buildMyJStree();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Sorry everyone.  Was digging through the Chrome debugger and realized that I had a CSS conflict happening between dependencies.

One of my dependencies had this style defined.  Once I disabled the margin-bottom property, the problem went away.

```
.h-entry ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: square;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```